# Training data for a recommender system of a location based social network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, social-networking, training-data

I'm currently developing a location based social network in Ruby on Rails. I also want to include a recommendation system. For testing the algorithms of this recommendations I need some real, anonymous training data. I've found the data from the [Netflix Prize](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/KDD-cup-2007/KDD-cup-2007-who-rated-what-in-2006-answers.txt), but they are only including .

I'm searching for data that includes

- users
- friendships
- locations or venues
- check-ins (like in foursquare)

Does anybody know a good source for such data? Or a proven algorithm for generating this data? Or any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally solved it by using the gowalla API. Here you get a lot of information about users, without asking the users to permit the access to their data (kinda strange, but it works).

check it out: http://gowalla.com/api/explorer#/users/sco

Answer (score 1):

Search for [random graph generation](http://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=random%20graph%20generation) algorithms (more prciese, "social graph generation") to simulate social graph. Try retrieving the some test geolocation data by Google maps API or similar services. Unfortunately, I don't know what is "check-ins (like in foursquare)".

Also see [Free Social Graph Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887168/free-social-graph-data)

Comment: thx for your answer. In foursquare (a location-based social network) you can check-in at locations with your smartphone. So you say "I'm currently here at that location" and your position in latitude and longitude is stored. Maybe you also know a algorithm or service for that.